# Maintain source code separately in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am having a requirement in react js like, a react project contains more components and modules which I don't want to maintain it in the same source code. So thought of maintaining it as a private NPM modules and import those modules (components and modules) whenever it's required. Is this is the right approach or any other alternative or better approaches are there?

Any help appreciated so I can complete this project.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Public) NPM module may be a bit 'too much' for just keeping the source code of parts of the project in different places.

NPM supports Github URLs though and I would take that path. Check their documentation here:

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But have a quick doubt that I can't share the source code in Github public..so thought of putting that source code in bitbucket private repository. How it will authenticate and get the source code from the bitbucket private repository?

Comment: You can also use git urls: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies - That should be the solution with bitbucket.

Comment: Thanks,....Any idea how to pass the data for the URL Git repository project and vice versa?

Comment: Not sure if I understand that. I assume, that you have your shared or separated components in a separate remote git repository and that you use that on the package.json of your main react project.